# How to convert "XX Days XX Hours XX Minutes" into seconds in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to convert "XX Days XX Hours XX Minutes" into seconds in SQL Server?
Ex: How to convert "3 Days 18 Hours 39 Minutes" into seconds in SQL Server?

Comment: Hi Raja.  Please refer to the guidelines at [ask] for help formulating your question.

Comment: How is the data being stored? Are their different attributes for the days, hours, and minutes? Are you creating a function? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `((3*24+18)*60+39)*60`. Works for any language

Comment: This smells like a homework question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: To All, My bad, I have not posted the question in the correct manner. Anyways Thanks for your suggestions and answers. I have found the answer to this issue as stated below.

Comment: with cte  as
(select '28m'  time
union                      
select '2h 8m'  time
union                     
select '15m 4s' time
union select '1d 5h 54m 6s'
union select '1d 21h 59m 48s' union select '10h 12m 2s')

select time, substring(time,CHARINDEX('d', time)-2,2)*86400 + 
substring(time,CHARINDEX('h', time)-2,2)*3600 + 
substring(time,CHARINDEX('m', time)-2,2)*60 + 
substring(time,CHARINDEX('s', time)-2,2) sec from cte

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764633/sql-server-converting-days-hours-minutes-to-seconds

Comment: I am upvoting, I think others didn't understand how literal your question should be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @formula varchar(1000)
set @formula = 'select ' + replace(replace(replace('2h 2m', ' ', '+'),'h','*60*60'),'m','*60')
execute(@formula)
```

Here is a more generic formula you can use. It is fairly error prone though

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Stack Overflow is a place where people ask assignment questions, or it is where folks would like to promote laziness. It's okay to be new to SQL or this platform, but commonsense shall tell that you've to do some research googling about your questions, and come up with more ideas and difficulties that require additional eyes. You can't afford craving for help in high school for a 1+1 Math question. Saying this, this will give you the seconds = 326340

```
SELECT ((((3*24) +18) *60) + 39) * 60
```

Comment: Please check my recent corrections in the question.
I have written it wrongly, thus it got impression that im doing some assignment work but thats not true my friend.